# How can I do 'early stopping' during fit() in tsai

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series

Below is my sample code from [tsai notebook](https://github.com/timeseriesAI/tsai/blob/main/tutorial_nbs/04_Intro_to_Time_Series_Regression.ipynb) for time series regression problem.

```
from tsai.all import *

dsid = 'AppliancesEnergy'
arch_config = {
    'hidden_size':100, 
    'n_layers':2, 
    'rnn_dropout':0.2, 
    'fc_dropout':0.5, 
    'bidirectional':True
    }

X, y, splits = get_regression_data(dsid, split_data=False)
learn = TSRegressor(
    X, 
    y, 
    splits=splits, 
    bs=128, 
    batch_tfms=[TSStandardize(by_sample=True)], 
    arch=LSTM, 
    arch_config=arch_config, 
    metrics=[mae, rmse], 
    cbs=ShowGraph(), 
    verbose=True)

learn.fit_one_cycle(100, lr_max=1e-3)
learn.plot_metrics()
```

This works good. What I want to do is Early Stopping during fit().
I found callbacks function 'TerminateOnNaNCallback()' for that in fastai and I applied it like below with import fastai.

```
learn.fit_one_cycle(100, lr_max=1e-3, cbs=TerminateOnNaNCallback())
```

But this does not work. If somebody knows, please let me know.
Thank you.